# How to style a AngularDart component using eventually multiple CSS files

Tags: css, angularjs, dart, angular-dart, shadow-dom

I was wondering what is the best way to style AngularDart components? I'd like to be able to split base styles into a separate CSS file and then just include it somehow (maybe `@import`, if angular dart supports it) in my component.

Standard `NgComponent` allows me to add only once CSS file, as in the following example:

```dart
@NgComponent(
  selector: 'rating',
  templateUrl: 'packages/angular_dart_demo/rating/rating_component.html',
  cssUrl: 'packages/angular_dart_demo/rating/rating_component.css',
  publishAs: 'ctrl',
  map: const {
    'max-rating': '@maxRating',
    'rating': '<=>rating'
})
```

What if my CSS is somehow split across multiple files, how do I include all of them in a component?

At the moment, I'm starting to notice that although AngularDart components help with making components reusable, they are not the most maintainable - there's lots of copy paste in CSS. If it was possible to split the styles the components would be a lot more maintainable (i.e. One can include base styles in multiple components - instead of copy-pasting them across every css file for each component).

What is the best way to structure components and css within AngularDart environment?

Comment: Why is this Dart's problem? Use semantic namespacing - give elements one class, 'baseComponent', and several additional classes as needed.

Comment: I agree on giving elements different classes. But because I want to reuse the same class across different NgComponent elements I have no way other then copy pasting, or making one gigantic css file and putting everything there and then including that file in each component - which is a nasty approach. Or maybe you know of a way to achieve this? @david-souther

Comment: Stylus / sass / less.

(I have no idea how AngularDart and NgComponent work - I'm a Coffee guy. I just find it a bit odd that it seems to completely lack modularity in its css.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the answer. To get a css into a component you can either use

1. @import in your css
2. cssUrls parameter -
   https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/315

Answer (score 4):

The attribute cssUrl and applyAuhtorStyles can both be applied at the same time, as shown below. As you can see, in addition to inheriting the parent styles (bootstrap for example), you can also add component specific styles (cssUrl) that are only available in the component scope.

---

```
@NgComponent(
selector: 'paginate',
templateUrl: 'component/paginate/paginate_component.html',
cssUrl: 'component/paginate/paginate_component.css',
applyAuthorStyles: true,
publishAs: 'ctrl',
map: const {
  'page-filter-map' : '<=>pageFilterMap'
}
```

)

---

There are also directives that can be used called cssStyle to add even more control, also shown below.

```
<span ng-style="{color:'red'}">Sample Text</span>
```

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem. The Author styles come from outside and I need all the styles to be isolated within the component.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/tree/master/Chapter_04/lib/rating

In the .dart file of the component there is an annotation that contains the attribute cssUrl. I am not sure but I think this couples the file to the encapsulating Web Component css.

```
@NgComponent(
    selector: 'rating',
    templateUrl: 'packages/angular_dart_demo/rating/rating_component.html',
    cssUrl: 'packages/angular_dart_demo/rating/rating_component.css',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    map: const {
      'max-rating' : '@maxRating',
      'rating' : '<=>rating'
    }
)
```

Note that in order for this packages/ link to work you need to have your files in the /lib folder.

Comment: I've seen this already. My questions is more like is there a way for me to somehow define styles in multiple css files and somehow include all of them in the component.

Comment: I don't think there is an option for that yet, seems like a candidate for a feature request at the Angular.dart GitHub although Components are meant to be isolated. The only way I think to solve this now is to replace cssUrl in the annotation with applyAuthorStyles: true.